# GCP pubsub with ordering key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Our spring boot app uses Messaging Gateway to publish and consume message from GCP pubsub. The existing topics and their subscriptions which we use does not have ordering enabled. Now we want to add a topic and subscription with ordering of messages enabled. I have tested this using a simple python script and works exactly as we want. Now I am implementing the publisher in our Spring boot app. The message gets published correctly but the ordering key which i am sending as the message header is not reflecting and my consumer also is not able to fetch it.

Here is the MessageGateway

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "OutboundChannel")
public interface FiFoGateway {
  void execute(T message);
}
```

Publisher code

```
Message<MyPubSubMessage> orderedMessage = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(pubSubMessage)
                .setHeader("orderingKey", "key1")
                .build();
fiFoGateway.execute(orderedMessage);
```

My publisher config

```
  @Bean("fIFOPublisher")
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "OutboundChannel")
  public PubSubMessageHandler fiFOPublisher(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
    return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubSubTemplate, "myTopic");
  }
```

My consumer also not consuming it.

It isappearing in the GCP page but we can see the ordering key colum in empty.
[image]

Not sure what am I missing ? Any suggestions or pointers ?

Comment: Did you try to purge your subscription and to test again? It could be old messages first.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I purged the messages and tried again. The ordering key is not coming in the new messages.

Comment: @TinyRick did you recreate subscription with ordering enabled or you are using old subscription?

Comment: @ChandanPasunoori I created a fresh topic and created a fresh subscription with ordering enabled. Still no luck.

The spring boot version i am using is 2.3.4 and spring cloud gcp version is 1.2.8.RELEASE. 

I suspect there is no support for ordering in this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Pub/Sub client APIs offer a flag that allows you to enable message ordering.

Using Spring Cloud GCP, which internally uses the Pub/Sub Java client library, the easiest way to set this flag is setting the [configuration property](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#publishersubscriber-configuration) `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.publisher.enable-message-ordering` to `true`, it is `false` by default.

Please, consider review the Spring GCP documentation, especially when they describe [ordering messages](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#publishersubscriber-configuration) when using `PubSubTemplate` and [mapping headers](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#header-mapping) with Spring integration.

Please, be aware that in order to use the mentioned configuration property you need at least the [`2.0.2` version](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#pubsub-8) of the Spring Cloud GCP Pub/Sub related libraries: the change was addressed in [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/408) and first included in the aforementioned library version.

If you cannot upgrade your libraries, you may try the following.

First, define a custom `PubSubMessageConverter`, the class in charge of performing the actual creation of the `PubSubMessage`s, to deal with message ordering, something like:

```java
public class OrderingAwarePubSubNessageConverter extends SimplePubSubMessageConverter {

  private final Charset charset;

  public OrderingAwarePubSubNessageConverter() {
    this(Charset.defaultCharset());
  }

  public OrderingAwarePubSubNessageConverter(Charset charset) {
    super(charset);

    this.charset = charset;
  }

  // Override the toPubSubMessage conversion method including the logic for ordering messages
  @Override
  public PubsubMessage toPubSubMessage(Object payload, Map<String, String> headers) {
    ByteString convertedPayload;
    if (payload instanceof ByteString) {
      convertedPayload = (ByteString)payload;
    } else if (payload instanceof String) {
      convertedPayload = ByteString.copyFrom(((String)payload).getBytes(this.charset));
    } else if (payload instanceof ByteBuffer) {
      convertedPayload = ByteString.copyFrom((ByteBuffer)payload);
    } else {
      if (!(payload instanceof byte[])) {
        throw new PubSubMessageConversionException("Unable to convert payload of type " + payload.getClass().getName() + " to byte[] for sending to Pub/Sub.");
      }

      convertedPayload = ByteString.copyFrom((byte[])payload);
    }

    PubsubMessage.Builder pubsubMessageBuilder = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(convertedPayload);
    if (headers != null) {
      pubsubMessageBuilder.putAllAttributes(headers);

      // This code is the one required for instructing PubsubMessage.Builder to order messages
      if (headers.containsKey("yourOrderingKeyHeader")) {
        pubsubMessageBuilder.removeAttributes("yourOrderingKeyHeader");
        pubsubMessageBuilder.setOrderingKey(headers.get("yourOrderingKeyHeader"));
      }
    }

    return pubsubMessageBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

Please, note the code related to ordering messages.

Then, configure your `PubSubTemplate` for using an instance of this new converter. Please, define in your code:

```java
pubSubTemplate.setMessageConverter(new OrderingAwarePubSubNessageConverter());
```

Comment: I actually followed this link
https://www.databasesandlife.com/spring-pubsub-ordering/

The link mentions the property enabling. However the spring version the link mentions is different from mine.


The spring boot version i am using is 2.3.4 and spring cloud gcp version is 1.2.8.RELEASE. 

I suspect there is no support for ordering in this version

Comment: You are right @TinyRick. Please, see the updated answer. Please, try upgrading the version of your Spring Cloud GCP library, I think it may be possible.

Comment: @TinyRick I updated the answer with a possible solution based on the library version you are currently using. I hope it helps.